# Chrome inspector doesn't show css line number anymore in many of the localhost sites

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

Every other website I visit, the inspector works as expected:

[image]

---

But in many of the sites I'm editing within apache server (using xampp) somehow they doesn't show the "filename.css:lineNumber" data

[image]

Also, every change I try to do in the inspector in thse sites, doesn't do anything to the code shown in the source tab.

I've tried refreshing, hard refreshing with cache, closing and opening the tab, closing and opening chrome again. The same problem occurs.

In other sites the inspector works well, but not in many of the localhost sites.
Has someone experienced this before? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Posted same question today but no replay yet :(

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a client-side CSS generator library such as Lea Verou's excellent [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) or client-side [Less](http://lesscss.org), you will not see source information as it has all been processed and reinjected as style elements.

Client-side Less has a property [dumpLineNumbers] to include source line info as a comment in the generated source. (I'm not sure if this will display in Chrome's inspector - but I think it might)

The only "fix" I know of for -prefix-free is to temporarily remove it, obtain the source info for reference, then put it back in.

Comment: I'm not using a css generator

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem (not using a css generator), and it appears to be a known bug with the current version of Chrome, the solution is to use the more up to date Beta version known as Chrome Canary - Here's the link :)

https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to check what the format of your CSS file is. I had the same trouble with the UNIX and Macintosh formats. For example, try to open you CSS file in Notepad++ and in the bottom right corner of the window you'll see your current format. If you see UNIX or Macintosh there, click it with the right button of your mouse and change to DOS/Windows. Then save your file and refresh your page in Chrome. It definitely helped in my case.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0TPu.png)